# Codeigniter active record where clause with values from two fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Am stuck trying to implement simple where clause in codeigniter. What I have is this

```
public function get_low_stock()
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->where('productQty <=' , '10'); //line where the problem is
            $this->db->from('products');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
```

I need the value '10' to be picked from the minQty colum, but have no way to implement this. Such that once I change the minQty in the database, automatically I get the correct low qty. Please see my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
`productid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `catid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productqty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `buyprice` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `saleprice` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `minqty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `maxqty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `alertlevel` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`productid`, `productname`, `catid`, `productqty`, `buyprice`, `saleprice`, `minqty`, `maxqty`, `alertlevel`) VALUES
(1, '2.6 china touch', 1, 9, 2500, 5000, 10, 100, 15),
(4, '2.9 china touch', 1, 10, 2500, 5000, 10, 100, 15),
(5, '3.0 small cable', 1, 5, 2500, 5000, 10, 100, 15);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this two way.

**1#**

```
$query=$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `products` where productqty <= minqty');
return $query->result();
```

**2#**

```
$this->db->select('*');        
$this->db->where('productqty <=minqty',null,false);
//or use this way
//$this->db->where('productqty <=minqty');
$this->db->from('products');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

**Note**
You used `productQty` but your database column name is `productqty`.It may work.But use the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$where = '(productQty <= minqty)';

$this->db->where($where);
```

as you mentioned minqty is dynamic in your code

```
$this->db->where('productQty <= minqty');
```

Comment: In my case I want it to be dynamic so that its picked from the minqty column and not set every time. i.e In the database I may change minqty for a product to 15. Then automatically the script should calculate basing on the new database value.

Comment: if i could understand your query it will be as this    ===>      select * from product where productty <= minqty rt?

Comment: You selected other answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at both answers you notice thy are quite the same with slight variation